# How to customize forms in Symfony 5 + EasyAdmin 3?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

***Following the examples provided in the documentation:***

https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
    # ...
    entities:
        Customer:
            class: App\Entity\Customer
            form:
                fields:
                    - id
                    - { type: 'section', label: 'User Details' }
                    - name
                    - surname
                    - { type: 'section', label: 'Contact information', icon: 'phone',
                        help: 'Phone number is preferred' }
                    - email
                    - phoneNumber
```

***Details:***

- I had to create the easyadmin.yaml file in the same address as the example, since I didn't have it.
- Not even the most basic example works.
- I imagine it will be because of the version, if it is the case, how the forms are edited in EasyAdmin 3

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/upgrade.html) yaml is no longer used in 3.x. You will need to use PHP to change stuff [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/fields.html#creating-custom-fields).